# migrate maven package from nexus to gitlab package registry

Tags: java, maven, nexus, artifact

I am using Nexus to store maven package and java artifact. My company want to use Gitlab package registry replacing for Nexus. There are a lot of maven package in Nexus (different version). How can I migrate or move all package from Nexus to Gitlab Package Registry.

Anyone have exp about this, please advise me! Thanks so much

Comment: Now i just write a script to download all packages from nexus. Then script will upload packages to gitlab package registry. it's done for me. If anyone can find another solutions, please instruct me. Thanks

Comment: would it be possible to have a copy of your script? thanks! i'm in the same situation here